# No me captura el error de mi procedimiento Spring Boot

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, stored-procedure, sql-server-2017

Tengo un procedimiento con raiserror y el spring no me captura el error o tal vez estoy haciendo algo mal. 
Dejo el codigo.

**Procedure**

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[SP_CRUD_USERS]
@OPCION INT = 0,
@NOM_USER VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
@EMA_USER VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
@COD_USER INT = 0
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    BEGIN TRY
        IF @OPCION = 1
            BEGIN
                SELECT * FROM TB_USERS
            END
        ELSE IF @OPCION = 2
            BEGIN
                IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TB_USERS WHERE EMA_USER = @EMA_USER)
                    BEGIN
                        IF @NOM_USER IS NULL OR @NOM_USER = '' AND @EMA_USER IS NULL OR @EMA_USER = ''
                            RAISERROR('Ingresar un dato para registrar',16,1)
                        ELSE
                            INSERT INTO TB_USERS VALUES (@NOM_USER, @EMA_USER)
                    END
                ELSE
                    RAISERROR('El email ya existe',16,1)
            END
        ELSE IF @OPCION = 3
            BEGIN
                IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TB_USERS WHERE COD_USER = @COD_USER)
                    BEGIN
                        IF @NOM_USER IS NULL OR @NOM_USER = '' AND @EMA_USER IS NULL OR @EMA_USER = ''
                            RAISERROR('Ingresar un dato para actualizar',16,1)
                        ELSE
                            UPDATE TB_USERS SET NOM_USER = @NOM_USER, EMA_USER = @EMA_USER WHERE COD_USER = @COD_USER
                    END
                ELSE 
                    RAISERROR('El usuario no existe',16,1)
            END
        ELSE IF @OPCION = 4
            BEGIN
                IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TB_USERS WHERE COD_USER = @COD_USER)
                    DELETE FROM TB_USERS WHERE COD_USER = @COD_USER
                ELSE 
                    RAISERROR('El usuario no existe',16,1)
            END
        END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()
    END CATCH
END
```

**Service**

```
@Service
public class CrudUserService implements CrudUserDAO{

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked" })
    @Override
    public ValidateApiResponse MntUser(Integer op, String nom, String ema, Integer cod) {
        ValidateApiResponse vapi = new ValidateApiResponse();
        Session session = em.unwrap(Session.class);
        try {
            ProcedureCall call = session.createStoredProcedureCall("SP_CRUD_USERS");
            call.registerParameter(1, Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN);
            call.registerParameter(2, String.class, ParameterMode.IN).enablePassingNulls(true);
            call.registerParameter(3, String.class, ParameterMode.IN).enablePassingNulls(true);
            call.registerParameter(4, Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN).enablePassingNulls(true);
            call.setParameter(1, op);
            call.setParameter(2, nom);
            call.setParameter(3, ema);
            call.setParameter(4, cod);
            vapi.dTable = call.getResultList();
            vapi.Attr = "OK";
            //call.execute();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            vapi.Error = e.getMessage();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return vapi;
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
@RestController
public class CrudUserController {

    @Autowired
    private CrudUserService service;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/CrudUsers", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody ApiResponse CrudUsers(@RequestParam(value = "option", required = true) Integer op,
                                 @RequestParam(value = "nomUser", required = false) String nom, 
                                 @RequestParam(value = "emaUser", required = false) String ema,
                                 @RequestParam(value = "codUser", required = false) Integer cod){

        ValidateApiResponse vapi = new ValidateApiResponse();
        ApiResponse  api = new ApiResponse();

        try {
            vapi = service.MntUser(op,nom,ema,cod);
            if (vapi.Error == null || vapi.Error == "") {
                if (vapi.Attr == "OK") {
                    api.MsjCode = 200;
                    api.Msj = "OK";
                    api.dtCollection = vapi.dTable;
                } else {
                    api.MsjCode = 400;
                    api.Msj = "Dismissed Request";
                    api.MsjDetail = vapi.Attr;
                }
            } else {
                api.Msj = "Internal Server Error";
                api.MsjDetail = vapi.Error;
                api.MsjCode = 500;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            api.Msj = "Internal Server Error";
            api.MsjDetail = e.getMessage();
            api.MsjCode = 500;
        }
        return api;
    }
}
```

**ApiResponse**

```
public class ApiResponse {

    public String Msj;
    public String MsjDetail;
    public List<Object> dtCollection;
    public int MsjCode;

    public ApiResponse() {
        this.Msj = "";
        this.MsjDetail = "";
        this.MsjCode = -1;
        this.dtCollection = new ArrayList<>();
    }       
}
```

**ValidateApiResponse**

```
public class ValidateApiResponse {

    public String Error;
    public String Attr;
    public List<Object> dTable;

    public ValidateApiResponse() {
        this.Error = "";
        this.Attr = "";
        this.dTable = new ArrayList<>();
    }   
}
```

Ademas tengo otro problema, cuando me muestra el json no me genera las "keys". Tal vez me diran que deba crear la entidad, pero yo quisiera que sea algo dinamico, tal vez agregar algunos datos mas al procedure y estar creando el atributo de esa entidad, me parece algo tedioso, pero quisas estea equivocado.

```
{
    "Msj": "OK",
    "MsjDetail": "",
    "dtCollection": [
        [
            1,
            "AAA",
            "AAA@HOTMAIL.COM"
        ],
        [
            2,
            "BBB",
            "BBB@HOTMAIL.COM"
        ],
        [
            3,
            "CCC",
            "CCC@HOTMAIL.COM"
        ]
    ],
    "MsjCode": 200
}
```

Ademas quisiera que estea dentro de corchetes y llaves osea [{3,"ccc","ccc@hotmail.com"}] algo asi